# How to enable calling USSD Code (*770#) on iOS 7 in Xcode by using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurl, ussd

I know how to call phone number (e.g.0615481129) from iPhone App using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:0615481129"]];
```

But for phone numbers with * or #, the above line is not responding (no error message as well):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:*770#"]];
```

please help me how to enable calling USSD Code (*770#) on iOS 7 in Xcode  by using Objective-C

Comment: yes I did not get yet the answer I am new in iOS programming language please help me this issue how to solve this and how to enable the using ussd code in my application  I am using objective c please tel me the steps do I fallow

Comment: You got the answer. You can't. You don't like the answer, but asking again won't change the answer.